# node Sass Support to current version environment (Ionic)

Tags: ionic2, node-sass

in the ionic app
trying to run ionic emulate ios but following error is coming

> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build /Users/farrukhqamar/HybridApps/helloWorld
>   ionic-app-scripts build

keywords if/then/else require v5 option
/Users/farrukhqamar/HybridApps/helloWorld/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:13
    throw new Error(errors.unsupportedEnvironment());
    ^

Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (51)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.10.1
    at Object. (/Users/farrukhqamar/HybridApps/helloWorld/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:13:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object. (/Users/farrukhqamar/HybridApps/helloWorld/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/sass.js:11:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)

In the morning every thing was working but just start happening now in my current project
If i create a new project then it runs perfectly.
I am very new in ionic so please suggest some solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime (Node Module ABI) version 51 means it's an Electron environment, which node-sass doesn't directly support.